Close Popover in vue when clicked on Link
Im currently working on a Navigationbar in vue.js.
I want to close (respectively, hide) the Dashboard when im clicking a link inside of it
With my current Solution its wokring but i have to click twice on the Dashboard(PopoverButton) to open the PopoverPanel again.
I think its because the popoverOpen ref first have to update and
only on second click it will open the panel again.
so its not a good solution for this problem
const popoverOpen = ref(false)

function closePopover() {
  console.log("Popover wird geschlossen")
  popoverOpen.value = false
}
function openPopover() {
  popoverOpen.value = true
}

Template:
PopoverGroup class="hidden lg:flex lg:gap-x-12">
    <Popover class="relative">
      <PopoverButton 
      class="flex items-center gap-x-1 text-sm/6 font-semibold text-[#E0D8DE] hover:text-[#949D6A]"
      @click="openPopover"
      >
        Dashboard
        <ChevronDownIcon class="size-5 flex-none text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
      </PopoverButton>

      <transition
        enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-200" 
        enter-from-class="opacity-0 translate-y-1" 
        enter-to-class="opacity-100 translate-y-0" 
        leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-150" 
        leave-from-class="opacity-100 translate-y-0" 
        leave-to-class="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
        >
      <PopoverPanel
      v-if="popoverOpen" 
      class="absolute -left-8 top-full z-10 mt-3 w-screen max-w-md overflow-hidden rounded-3xl bg-[#1a1a1a] shadow-lg ring-1 ring-gray-900/5"
      >
        <div class="p-4">
          <div v-for="item in products" :key="item.name" class="group relative flex items-center gap-x-6 rounded-lg p-4 text-sm/6 hover:bg-[#423E37]">
            <div class="flex size-11 flex-none items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gray-50 group-hover:bg-white">
              <component :is="item.icon" class="size-6 text-gray-600 group-hover:text-indigo-600" aria-hidden="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="flex-auto">
              <router-link 
                v-if="item.href" 
                :to="item.href" 
                class="block font-semibold text-[#949D6A]"                       
                @click="closePopover"          
                >
                {{ item.name }}
              </router-link>
              <p class="mt-1 text-[#E0D8DE]">{{ item.description }}</p>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid grid-cols-2 divide-x divide-gray-900/5 bg-gray-50">
            <a v-for="item in callsToAction" :key="item.name" :href="item.href" class="flex items-center justify-center gap-x-2.5 p-3 text-sm/6 font-semibold text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-100">
              <component :is="item.icon" class="size-5 flex-none text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
              {{ item.name }}
            </a>
          </div>
        </PopoverPanel>
      </transition>
    </Popover>

  </PopoverGroup>

Question: Has anyone a good and clean solution for this problem.

The question is unclear. It countains no PopoverGroup, etc, it's uknown if they contribute to the problem. There's nothing "nasty" in having a state when you need one. "and to open the Dropdown again, you'll have to click twice" - please, explain why is that. There's no mention of "Dropdown" in the question.

thanks for the help: updated the post:)

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unclear what it is, could depend on PopoverPanel. There's no such problem in general with double clicking. If you update the state, it's applied to the template
